# Does SPIM use my CPU's registers?

Tags: mips, spim

When I am simulating MIPS with SPIM, when I operate on registers within the SPIM simulator am I actually using the registers on my CPU? I am running SPIM on an Intel machine.

Comment: Only in a very general sense - there is no mapping of registers - your real CPU is just executing code like it would for any other program.

Answer (score 2):

No, SPIM is a simulator, i.e. it *simulates* real processor, but nothing more. There is no need, nor possibility to do so (MIPS and x86 processors have different register sets).

However, in the end, the SPIM itself is using your processor's registers of course.